# Communication between Header and Component not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get a button in a Header component (using navigation options) to properly call a function in another Screen component. I can get the function to trigger, but it does not work as expected. Almost like its using different states.

Here is my test scenario. I have a button in the header and a button in the screen. Both buttons trigger the same toggle function that flips the ReadOnly state.

[image]

In my component as follows. This simply calls the onSavedFn passed in the params

```
MyScreen.navigationOptions = navData => {
return {   
    headerTitle: 'Test',
    headerRight: (props) => 
    <View style={{height: 60}}>
        <Button title='Toggle 1'
                onPress={() =>{
                    const onSavedFn = navData.navigation.getParam('onSaved');
                    onSavedFn();
                }}
        />
    </View>
}
```

I pass the function in a useEffect function:

```
const MyScreen = props => {
    const [readOnly, setReadOnly] = useState(true);
    ...

    useEffect(() => {
        props.navigation.setParams({
            onSaved: toggleSaved,
        });
    }, [toggleSaved]); //, props.navigation]);

    const toggleSaved = () => {
        console.log('toggleSaved: readOnly=' + readOnly.toString());
        setReadOnly(!readOnly);
    };
    ...
}
```

Now, when I toggle the button in the Screen component, the readOnly state flips back and forth as expected.

```
toggleSaved: readOnly=true
toggleSaved: readOnly=false
toggleSaved: readOnly=true
toggleSaved: readOnly=false
toggleSaved: readOnly=true
```

When I toggle the button in the header, it calls the function and will flip the state from True to False, but never the other direction.

```
toggleSaved: readOnly=true
toggleSaved: readOnly=false
toggleSaved: readOnly=false
toggleSaved: readOnly=false
```

Same code. Same function. But the button from the header can only change the state once or in one direction.

I am flummuxed and been staring and trying to solve this for a while. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit:
Here is an working example of my issue
https://snack.expo.io/@dbh21/headercommunicationtest

Comment: sounds like the navigation state in the header is not getting updated, so it always thinks its true, so the value always comes back false

Comment: what does `const onSavedFn = navData.navigation.getParam('onSaved'); onSavedFn();` do? you call setParams in one component and not the other, perhaps thats the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I see the issue, so you need to change your data flow.

In the header component, you want to use navigation.setParam to flip the readonly bool.

In the component you want to just refer to the param, there is no reason to have an extra state to represent that value.

```
MyScreen.navigationOptions = screenProps => {
    return {
      headerTitle: 'Test',
      headerRight: (props) =>
        <View style={{ height: 60 }}>
          <Button title='Toggle 1'
            onPress={() => {
              const isReadOnly = screenProps.navigation.getParam('isReadOnly');
              screenProps.navigation.setParams({
                isReadOnly: !isReadOnly,
              });
            }}
          />
        </View>
    }
  }

  const MyScreen = props => {
    const { navigation } = props;

    const toggleSaved = () => {
      const isReadOnly = navigation.getParams('isReadOnly')
      props.navigation.setParams({
        isReadOnly: !isReadOnly,
      });
    };
  }
```

Comment: I'm confused. Why can't I just call a function and manage the state within the same component? Are you suggesting the data cannot be passed bi-directionally?

I added this to update the header when the readOnly changes

`useEffect(() => {
        props.navigation.setParams({
            readOnly: readOnly,            
        });
      }, [readOnly]);
`
But it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: the variable `onSaved` and `readOnly` are the same value, there is no need to sync it within the component with `useState`, you are keeping the state within the navigation/screen params already

Comment: Ultimately, I was trying to have the header call a function in the screen, and the screen manage the state (more than just readOnly flag, title and stats). But the function call is like it sees a different state model or something.

Comment: as a rule of thumb in react, you shouldn't pass state up to a parent component, in this case the screen, its better to pass state down. If you are passing state up, the triggering of state changes in the parent gets tricky and you wind up with parents being out of sync with their children

Comment: if you wanted to do it your original way (not recommended) just add this to your `toggleSaved` function `props.navigation.setParams({onSaved: !isReadOnly});`

Comment: Thanks. Let me play around with this and try to understand it

BTW... in this case, my header title will change depending on a user selection in the screen. So I think keeping the state in the screen makes sense since it has title and other things.But I'm new to react

Comment: Hi Eric. I made an example of my issue here https://snack.expo.io/@dbh21/headercommunicationtest, Would you mind taking a look? 

I just want the header to display data from the screen but to trigger events as well. This is showing my issue. Thanks

Comment: here is the snack of the solution i proposed, not sure why you are against it but its much cleaner this way -> https://snack.expo.io/@ehassey/headercommunicationtest

Comment: Hey thanks Eric. I was not against it. I see this works. But I am still trying to understand why the old one did not.

Comment: The other way you had would work but the crucial part is the setting of the screen params, its the only way to communicate the change back up to the header component, i went to check your old snack but it looks like you have changed it since then